# probability tree diagrams question

Tags: probability

[image]

Is there an easier way to do this question because doing a tree diagram four times with 3 outcomes each becomes very long

Comment: The request is explicit: through the tree diagram.

Comment: Not sure the problem is clear.  If he studies more than six hours,  is that a fail?

Comment: not too sure answer is 10 doing the tree diagram four times with 3 outcomes each time becomes very tedious

Comment: [OEIS A027907](https://oeis.org/A027907) provides several different approaches (you want $T(4,6)=10$) though using a tree diagram would probably be faster than reading all the links there

Comment: @lulu "A total of six hours", in my opinion it's like to say "not more than six".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long for a comment).

Just to say, you can make trees diagrams in an easier way.

$6$ hours in $4$ consecutive days, with the possibility of studying $0, 1$ or $2$ hours at most each day.

Then it's clear that if you start with $0$ hours the first day, the following days you must study $2$ hours per day. This gives the "sequence"

$$0 -- 2 -- 2 -- 2$$

and here you can permute the $0$, obtaining a total of $4$ possibilities.
Then considering the useful permutations (the distinct ones) you can just draw a single tree and consider its unique permutations, without drawing the others.

Again, if you study $1$ hour during the first day, then there is no way you can study $0$ hours at any other day. You're forced to study at least $1$ hour during one day and $2$ hours on the other two days, hence the sequence

$$1 -- 1 -- 2 -- 2$$

again with the unique permutations, obtaining $6$ possibilities.

There are no other possibilities.

Hence $10$ possibilities in total.

Comment: That's what I did as well I knew that there two cases 0222 and 1212 but these can be arranged differently so I used permutations formula (4!/3!)+(4!/2!2!)